# Powershell send-mailmessage with body text not working in batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Need help converting PowerShell commands to run in batch. I can get the following to run fine as .ps1:

```
$filecontent = Get-Content -path C:\temp\status.txt | Out-string
Send-MailMessage  -to   "tester@test.com"   -from   "ServerAdmin@test.com"  -subject "STATUS: PASS"      -body "$filecontent" -smtpServer mail2.co.test.ca.us
```

When I put it into a batch:

```
PowerShell  -command "$filecontent = Get-Content -path C:\temp\status.txt | Out-String" ^
Powershell  -command Send-MailMessage        ^
    -to      \"tester@test.com\"        ^
    -from    \"ServerAdmin@test.com\"       ^
    -subject \"STATUS: PASS \"      ^
    -body    \"$filecontent\" ^
    -smtpServer     mail2.co.test.ca.us
```

I get this error:

> ```
> Out-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Send-MailMessage'.
> At line:1 char:55
> + ... tatus.txt | Out-String Send-MailMessage -to "tester@test.com" -from " ...
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Out-String], ParameterBindingException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutStringCommand
> ```

Is the only way to make this work in a batch is to put the original PowerShell syntax into a .ps1 and call it from the batch? The send-mail portion works fine. Tried the $filecontent line without " and -Raw instead of the pipe and Out-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to put it in one command :

```
PowerShell  -command "$filecontent = Get-Content -path d:\temp\status.txt | Out-String; Send-MailMessage -to \"tester@test.com\" -from \"ServerAdmin@test.com\" -subject \"STATUS: PASS \"  -body \"$filecontent\" -smtpServer     mail2.co.test.ca.us"
```

Because in the second command `$filecontent` no longer exist.

Comment: OMG! is that all i needed was a ";" to join the commands?  Good lord, thanks man!  Works!